# Can't get url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phalcon

I have used ajax url with one parameter month which i selected from option box

```
  $.ajax({
    url: baseUri + 'attendancelist/search/attsearch/month/' + month ,
    type: 'GET'
    ...
        });
```

So i want to call that parameter in my **attsearchAction()**
So i code like this

```
public function attsearchAction() {        
    $month = $this->request->get('month');  //current testing framework is phalcon
    //$month = $this->_request->getParam('month'); //zend framework is ok by getParam
    var_dump($month);exit;     //null
   }
```

But it only show null? How to fix that>>

Comment: Have you stored variable month used in Ajax?

Comment: I stored variable by id ...
//var month = document.getElementById('month').value;

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing Phalcon url parameters `attendancelist/search/attsearch/month/[monthValue]` with GET parameters (`?month=[monthValue]`).

In Phalcon you would have to set up your router to know which part of the url is the parameter.

```
$router->add(
    "attendancelist/search/:action/month/{month}",
    array(
        "controller" => [your controller],
        "action"     => 1
    )
);
```

(See [the Phalcon Router docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html) for more information)

Then in your action you would have to get the parameters from the dispatcher.

```
public function attsearchAction() {
    $month = $this->dispatch->getParam('month');
    var_dump($month);exit;
   }
```

or

```
public function attsearchAction($month) {
    var_dump($month);exit;
   }
```

Comment: If you are going to send a JSON response remember to deactivate your view, `$this->view->deactivate()`

Comment: Yes @James Fenwick ,but want to call url is from jquery ,not in php phalcon!! Is there no ways anymore ,sir !!!!

Comment: You either have to change your jQuery to @Chayan's HTTP GET style or change your backend script to the style in my answer to make it work with your existing REST like style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass parameter with url than you should use `?` to pass parameter

```
url: baseUri + 'attendancelist/search/attsearch/?month=' + month
```

Alternately, as you are using ajax, so you can send the data using ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUri + 'attendancelist/search/attsearch/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {month: month},
    ...
});
```